Kicad 8: why do reference and value sometimes rotate with 'R' and sometimes not?
I am quite new to KiCAD, but I noticed that in the Schematic Editor keyboard 'R' sometimes rotates the symbol without rotating the text and sometimes rotates the text with it. What causes it? Is there a way to force the "text not to rotate" behaviour?
I know that I can rotate text separately when I solely select the text. I am just curious.
Left: before one rotation. Right: after one rotation.



Could it depend if the text is highlighted or not when pressing R. So maybe if you clicked on the component to select it or you used rectangular selection?

I used the same method for both D1 and D4 - just clicking on the symbol (not the text part). I also noticed that freshly inserted symbols don't rotate the text until the symbol is mirrored ('X'). My best guess is that mirroring or altering the symbol any other way turns the default library symbol into a local graphic object (or something like that).

Seems like a bug to me. I don't think this behavior is intended.

You can restore the default rotation behavior by using "Autoplace Fields" when the symbol is selected (Hotkey o).

Thank you @nanash1 ! That's exactly what I was looking for!
